# Install Tensorflow 1.8 in Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, installation

As we all know that Python2.7 came to an end and pip will stop supporting it from 2021 Jan.

Is it possible to install Tensorflow 1.8 version, I want to demo something in my college which uses FaceNet and Tensorflow 1.8 version now I can't replicate it in my new laptop.

If there is any possibility to install please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The official TensorFlow 1.8.0 wheels can be found on PyPI:

- [tensorflow==1.8.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.8.0/#files)
- [tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.8.0/#files)

If you have a Python 2.7 installation with `pip`, then you can install with

```
python2.7 -m pip install URL_TO_WHEEL
```

where `URL_TO_WHEEL` is a URL to the wheel file on PyPI (e.g., https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/0e/8af18d9169ed4f1a1c72cd50defd95b8382a12f2cf7cb9b76ba053db79ad/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl).

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response, yes this works for Linux and MacOs, is the same thing possible for Windows 10?